# am335x use gpio with pull down

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I'm working with a custom made mini computer, [am335x](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/processors/sitara/arm_cortex-a8/am335x/overview.page) based. 
It comes with 2 GPIO ports that we use to provide services to our customers.

I want to change one of those specific ports, that is already being attached to a specific device, to use an internal pull down.

The port is always with value 1 when no voltage is provided, and I need to change that because when that device provide no voltage, it has the same internal state has when it provides 0V.

This is the information of the specific pin:

```
    root@be905g:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/* | grep "pin 20"
    pin 20 (44e10850.0)
    pin 20 (44e10850.0): 48302180.eqep (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_eqep1 group pinmux_eqep1
    pin 20 (44e10850.0) 0000002e pinctrl-single
```

I saw that the "0x2e" value that is associated to the pin should be "0x27".

I've modified the DTS file and recompiled, and even with 0x27 in memory the port behaves as having a pull up.

I've used the command:

```
    mem_util 0x44e10850
```

and it returned 0x27, but still.

This is how the pin description in the ".dts" file I decompiled from the shipped ".dtb "looks:

```
    pinmux_eqep1 {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <0x50 0x2e 0x54 0x36>;
                linux,phandle = <0x40>;
                phandle = <0x40>;
            };
```

Comment: Is this mini computer available in the market. BTW is this a beaglebone black. What is the attached specific device? Can you post part schematic area of interest?

Comment: That mini computer is customly made for my company. From our perspective, it has 2 GPIO ports. How they are connected to the board is somewhat out of our reach. From the information i've collected it is similar to a beaglebone back in specs, but it is definitely not one. I understand from your post, your concern that there is physical pull up in the board. That might be the case. But I can't really provide more information.

Comment: Your other option is connect the pin to different device you have control check the behavior. At this time with out additional infomation I am unable to help you. Hopefully someone else can. Good luck.